# [SOLVE]Difference of two consecutive rows

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Hi i have a result like this from my query.

[query result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j09dA.png)

and i want to get the difference of a specific epmloyee break time so i need to minus the time (OUT-IN).

I have search the net but i see nothing related to my problem.

sample data below to make things more better.

```
ID  Date-TIme           Log-Type
1   2020-02-03 01:52:01   IN
2   2020-02-03 02:00:50   OUT
3   2020-02-03 03:12:14   IN
4   2020-02-03 03:48:55   OUT
5   2020-02-03 05:22:00   OUT
6   2020-02-03 21:59:52   IN
7   2020-02-03 21:59:57   IN
8   2020-02-03 22:20:21   OUT
```

expected result.

```
ID  Date-TIme           Log-Type       RESULT
1   2020-02-03 01:52:01   IN
2   2020-02-03 02:00:50   OUT
3   2020-02-03 03:12:14   IN           1:12
4   2020-02-03 03:48:55   OUT
5   2020-02-03 05:22:00   OUT
6   2020-02-03 21:59:52   IN           5:38
7   2020-02-03 21:59:57   IN
8   2020-02-03 22:20:21   OUT
```

My query on getting the result.

```
  SELECT L.NEVENTLOGIDN, LPAD (nuserid, 6, '0') nuserid, u.susername, 
    TO_CHAR (TO_DATE ('1970-01-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') + ( (ndatetime) / (60 * 60 * 24)), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') 
    date_time, l.nreaderidn, r.sname, 
    CASE WHEN l.nreaderidn IN (SELECT nreaderidn FROM tb_reader where sdescription in(Select Distinct SDESCRIPTION from TB_READER where SDESCRIPTION is not null and SDESCRIPTION not Like '%IN%' and SDESCRIPTION not like '%OUT%') and upper(sname) like '%' || upper('OUT') || '%') THEN 'OUT' 
    WHEN l.nreaderidn  IN (SELECT nreaderidn FROM tb_reader where sdescription in(Select Distinct SDESCRIPTION from TB_READER where SDESCRIPTION is not null and SDESCRIPTION not Like '%IN%' and SDESCRIPTION not like '%OUT%') and upper(sname) like '%' || upper('IN') || '%') THEN 'IN' END logtype 
   FROM TB_EVENT_LOG l, TB_READER r, TB_USER u 
   WHERE 
   l.nreaderidn IN (SELECT nreaderidn FROM tb_reader where sdescription in(Select Distinct SDESCRIPTION from TB_READER where SDESCRIPTION is not null and SDESCRIPTION not Like '%IN%' and SDESCRIPTION not like '%OUT%')) 
   AND NDATETIME >= (trunc(sysdate -1) - TO_DATE ('1970-01-01 12:00:00 AM', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS AM')) * 24 * 60 * 60 
   AND ndatetime <= (trunc(sysdate) - TO_DATE ('1970-01-01 12:00:00 AM', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS AM')) * 24 * 60 * 60 
   AND l.nuserid = u.suserid 
   AND l.nreaderidn = r.nreaderidn                           
   ORDER BY 2, 4;
```

It is normal in data to have a consecutive IN or OUT in that case i need to get the latest.
here's my attemp.

```
SELECT L.NEVENTLOGIDN, nuserid, u.susername, 
    TO_CHAR (TO_DATE ('1970-01-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') + ( (ndatetime) / (60 * 60 * 24)), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') 
    date_time, l.nreaderidn,R.SDESCRIPTION , r.sname, 
    CASE WHEN l.nreaderidn IN (SELECT nreaderidn FROM tb_reader where sdescription in(Select Distinct SDESCRIPTION from TB_READER where SDESCRIPTION is not null and SDESCRIPTION not Like '%IN%' and SDESCRIPTION not like '%OUT%') and upper(sname) like '%' || upper('OUT') || '%') THEN 'OUT' 
    WHEN l.nreaderidn  IN (SELECT nreaderidn FROM tb_reader where sdescription in(Select Distinct SDESCRIPTION from TB_READER where SDESCRIPTION is not null and SDESCRIPTION not Like '%IN%' and SDESCRIPTION not like '%OUT%') and upper(sname) like '%' || upper('IN') || '%') THEN 'IN' END logtype ,
    CASE WHEN log_type = 'IN' AND LAG(log_type) OVER (PARTITION BY employee ORDER BY date_time) = 'OUT' THEN DATEDIFF(date_time, LAG(date_time) OVER (PARTITION BY employee ORDER BY date_time)) ELSE NULL END remarks
   FROM TB_EVENT_LOG l, TB_READER r, TB_USER u 
   WHERE 
   l.nreaderidn IN (SELECT nreaderidn FROM tb_reader where sdescription in(Select Distinct SDESCRIPTION from TB_READER where SDESCRIPTION is not null and SDESCRIPTION not Like '%IN%' and SDESCRIPTION not like '%OUT%')) 
   AND NDATETIME >=  (trunc(sysdate -1) - TO_DATE ('1970-01-01 12:00:00 AM', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS AM')) * 24 * 60 * 60 
   AND ndatetime <=  (trunc(sysdate) - TO_DATE ('1970-01-01 12:00:00 AM', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS AM')) * 24 * 60 * 60 
   AND l.nuserid = u.suserid 
   AND l.nreaderidn = r.nreaderidn                           
   ORDER BY 2, 4;
```

this give error of `ORA-00904: "DATEDIFF": invalid identifier`
Hope someone help me out with this.
Thank you in advance

**UPDATE**
Update i insert the result of my select statement  in a table named TB_IN_OUT  now my query looks like this.

```
    Select USERID,USERNAME,READERNAME,DATE_TIME,LOGTYPE,
   CASE WHEN LOGTYPE = 'IN' AND LAG(LOGTYPE) OVER (PARTITION BY USERNAME ORDER BY DATE_TIME) = 'OUT' THEN 
   LAG(to_Date(DATE_TIME)) OVER (PARTITION BY DATE_TIME ORDER BY DATE_TIME) - to_date(DATE_TIME)

    ELSE NULL END
    from TB_IN_OUT
```

but returns error of

```
literal does not match format string
```

**UPDATE**

```
Select t.*,

        CASE WHEN LOGTYPE = 'IN' AND LAG(LOGTYPE) OVER (PARTITION BY USERNAME ORDER BY DATE_TIME) = 'OUT' THEN 

             --Round( (to_date(DATE_TIME,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS ') - to_date(LAG(DATE_TIME) OVER (PARTITION BY USERNAME ORDER BY DATE_TIME),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS ')) * 24,1)
             (to_date(DATE_TIME,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS ') - to_date(LAG(DATE_TIME) OVER (PARTITION BY USERNAME ORDER BY DATE_TIME),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS ')) * 24

       end as result

From TB_IN_OUT t
 where t.DATE_TIME like '%2020-01-31%'
```

result of the datetime difference like this.

```
5.43333333333333 
0.0536111111111111
2.60583333333333
```

expected result.

```
05:26:00
00:03:13
02:36:21
```

Comment: Why second result is 5:38?

Comment: maybe just my wrong calculation

Comment: Remove the to_date as it seems that datetime itself is of date data type.

Comment: no the DateTime is a varchar2 data type

Comment: Then provide the valid date format as `to_date(datetime, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')`

Comment: after i did that i did not get the difference all goes to else null

Comment: See my answer now!!

Comment: Some remarks: 1. You are using an ancient join syntax. Please use explicit joins instead (`from t1 join t2 on ...`). 2. You are calculating dates from strings. Use date literals instead, e.g. `date '1970-01-01'`. 3. Qualify all columns when working with different tables. Where do the columns `date_time`, `ndatetime`, `log_type`, `employee` reside in? 4. Why is there both `date_time` and `ndatetime` in the tables? Do they have different meanings? If not, then just have one datetime in the table and use the appropriate datatype `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` depending on the desired precision.

Comment: 5. Use explicit names in an `ORDER BY` clause, not positions, to get the query better readable and maintainable. 6. You may want to use a `WITH` clause or just join a subquery instead of writing the same subquery multiple times.

Comment: Please post sample data which matches your query. Or else simplify your query to match the sample data.

Comment: sorry i updated my question

Answer (score 1):

If your data looks like as per the sample data then you just need to use lag function as following:

```
Select t.*,
       Case when lag(log_type) over (partition by username, trunc(datetime) order by datetime) = 'OUT' 
                 and logtype = 'IN' 
            then to_char(trunc(sysdate) + (datetime - lag(datetime) over (partition by username, trunc(datetime) order by datetime)),'hh24:mi') 
       end as result
From your_table t
```

Please consider changing the datetime to date data type using `to_date`

Cheers!!

Comment: it can occur when date in your table (string) do not match the format string passed in `to_date` function.

Comment: i already got the result but i'm strugling with the decimal to hours and minutes convertion. i updated my question

Comment: `select to_char(trunc(sysdate) + 5.43333333333333/24, 'hh24:mi') from dual;`